# Best practices for add/edit activities

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-activity

Say I am developing an app for an Object. The app lets user add Object, open its details and edit Object - a very common setup.
I would create an AddObjectActivity which would contain all the input fields required to create Object. Once the Object is created - it can be edited and the edit activity should contain all the fields that create had. That means binding all the fields that create activity has and doing any layout setup - the same as create activity.

It seems to me that I have two options here: duplicate the code completely - create separate activities for add and edit actions OR reuse as much as possible and extend/introduce some kind of indicator indicating which of the actions(add or edit) is being performed.

Duplicating that much code feels wrong and the second option brings a lot of unneccessarty complexity.

This is a very common pattern in applications so I was wondering what is the best way of doing this in Android?

Comment: use same activity for creating and editing of content, add some check for editing and adding, and it will be easy to manage

Answer (score 2):

Use the same activity, when you need to update an Object you have to pass it through Intent Extra like this

```
intent.putExtra("object", myObject);
```

when start second activity you will get that extras like this

```
Object myObject = (Object) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("object");
```

the trick is when (myObject != null) then i'm in update mode, otherwise i'm in add mode, if in update mode put add object values that match activity field like (EditText, TextView .. etc)

if you need to know if activity finished with update mode you should start it using startActivityForResult() and get data back  in the implementation of onActivityResult()

i hope this will help you